# How do I enable comment replies on my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook-pages

In the last two month I have seen Facebook pages that have a comment reply button but my page doesn't have it. How can I enable this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add **reply feature** to comments on your Facebook page, you need to follow these steps -

1. First of all go to your Facebook page and in the admin panel, click
   Edit page > Manage Permissions.
2. Now scroll down to the bottom of the page and there you will see a
   reply option.
3. Simply check/tick this option to enable it.
4. Click Save Changes and you are done.

Once you enable it, will be shown for new posts/updates, it won't be activated for existing published updates.

For detailed tutorial please visit: [Enable 'Reply-to-Comment' feature right now](http://www.sociobits.org/2013/03/enable-reply-to-comment-on-facebook.html)

*Note: this is for a group or page that you manage, not for your personal Facebook page/profile.*

Comment: The Answer given is for Admins of Facebook Groups or Facebook Pages .... **NOT for one's own personal Facebook page.** **Personal FB pages or one's Profile Page does not have an Admin Panel.** So, the answer given, which is the reason for my showing up here, neither answered the question nor is helpful ... UNLESS you are a person who is an Admin of a Group who want to know how to enable comment replies for your Group. aaaarrrrgh

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to have **[Admin](https://www.facebook.com/help/323502271070625)** Rights:
Go to your page admin panel select **Edit page** tab **-->** select **Edit Settings**.  
[image]

Click on Edit option in **Replies**, and tick **Allow replies to comments on my page.** and **Save**.
[image]
Now you can see **Reply** option in page comments. 
[image]

Cheers!..

Comment: You might note that this does not apply for personal profiles.

Comment: You must note that, I given answer for Question "How do I enable comment replies on my Facebook page", not for personal profiles.