# Enabled Reply in comments on Facebook profile?

Tags: facebook, comments

I know you can enable "reply" feature on Facebook pages, but can this also be done on your personal profile? I've seen a few people on my FB list who have this feature enabled on their profile and their friends profiles too.

Does anyone have a guidance on this?

Comment: This has been asked many times. Check this 
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/38973/how-do-i-enable-comment-replies-on-my-facebook-page

Comment: @Deepak: The OP is asking about his personal timeline, not a page. The question you linked doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't enable “reply-to-comment” feature on your personal profile. But if you have more than 10,000 followers on your profile, it automatically applies to your account. Currently, there is no option to enable the feature by yourself on your Facebook Profile.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can now, although I am still unsure as to how. Maybe it is just a feature in New Zealand's Facebook, but I see my friends from NZ having replies on their comments.

Comment: Interesting. I'm going to try out a few things to see if I can manipulate that to my `Facebook` page too.